# String array parameter not recognized

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am trying to post form data with one field having string array. All other fields get posted but this string array is not recognized by my server.

```
let courses = ["course1", "course2"]
let params: Parameters = [
                "username": username,
                "fullname": fullname,
                "courses[]": courses
            ]
let request = Alamofire.request(self.BaseURL.appendingPathComponent("wp-json/form/ld/register"), method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil)
```

On my php end the courses field does not recognize as an array. Here is the debug log from `Alamofire`:

```
$ curl -v \
    -X POST \
    -b "PHPSESSID=gvaiuno75dotnb57lv08llslg3" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" \
    -d "courses%5B%5D=%5B%course1%22%2C%course2%22%5D&username=test-user&fullname=Test-User" \
    "https://wordpress-258834-806478 .........."
```

Comment: Hi @codelearner, change this line `let request = Alamofire.request(self.BaseURL.appendingPathComponent("wp-json/form/ld/register"), method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)` maybe it is works for you.

Comment: I tried that but the other parameters also does not get recognized.

Comment: `"courses[]": courses` => `"courses": courses`? What's your target output?

Comment: Thanks @Larme I tried this and it works.